# The "time.sleep" function provides unstable results depending on the specified time

Tags: python

im on windows 10 x64.
The "time.sleep" function is behaving somewhat strangely. When you run the code below, you can obtain reasonably stable results. However, increasing the value of "time.sleep" by just a bit yields significantly peculiar outcomes.

```
import time    

while True:
    abc = time.time()
    time.sleep(0.01)
    print (time.time()-abc)
```

result

```
0.015055656433105469
0.014978647232055664
0.014963626861572266
0.014959335327148438
0.014959335327148438
0.014989137649536133
0.0153045654296875
0.014065980911254883
0.014964103698730469
0.014961957931518555
0.014959573745727539
0.014799833297729492
0.013964414596557617
0.01413583755493164
0.014795541763305664
0.01498723030090332
0.014991044998168945
0.013995647430419922
0.013949871063232422
```

now with time.sleep(0.02)

```
0.03069162368774414
0.02988719940185547
0.02991962432861328
0.03043198585510254
0.030425548553466797
0.030948877334594727
0.02963709831237793
0.030451536178588867
0.029952287673950195
0.030124664306640625
0.030530691146850586
0.030917882919311523
0.03216052055358887
0.03042125701904297
0.029927968978881836
0.030064821243286133
0.029872655868530273
0.030456066131591797
0.030440568923950195
0.02991962432861328
0.030575990676879883
0.030539751052856445
0.029937744140625
0.030297279357910156
0.030652999877929688
0.031024932861328125
0.030635595321655273
0.029764652252197266
0.0298917293548584
0.029951810836791992
0.03045940399169922
0.029918670654296875
```

Is there a specific reason why the results are coming out so unstably?

Comment: these results seem the same to me... maybe I just haven't had my coffee, but this is within the realm of what I would expect, and both look to be behaving similarly (if anything, the first one is more unstable)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga surely the biggest discrepancy comes from the `print()` overhead here. That should be a fixed offset, so it is adding `0.005` in the first case. Instead it looks like the inflation of the sleep time is %age based. It shouldn't scale with the longer sleep time

Comment: By "fixed" I'm being fast and loose with terminology, but the OP's output suggests the discrepancy scales with the duration of the sleep

Comment: I had someone I trust test this on Windows and it's a no-repro. Not only does the discrepancy not make sense, but they can't back it up with testing. Your question is incomplete

Comment: You need to provide information around your system clock -- `time.get_clock_info("time")`, what is your CPU and motherboard and do you get the same results with `time.perf_counter`?

Comment: @roganjosh What print() overhead? The printing happens outside the measurement.

Comment: @KellyBundy of course it doesn't. The function call overhead is within the loop, plus the variability of the OS

Comment: @roganjosh Hmm? Yes, it's within the loop, but outside of each measurement. *After* the second `time()` call.

Comment: more importantly, *where* are you running this? Normal python console or some other places? (e.g: specific terminal, IDE, etc)

Comment: forgot to mention too, but what's your python version? exact one. Use `import sys; print(sys.version)`

Answer (score 1):

There may be some more particular answers, but it's important to note that [time.sleep](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) is not precisely guaranteed to return. In particular:

> The suspension time may be longer than requested by an arbitrary amount, because of the scheduling of other activity in the system.

`time.sleep` actually relinquishes control of the process to the operating system. Obviously it's true that all processes are controlled by the operating system but a typically running process runs in the foreground and will take as much CPU as allowed. For instance:

```
while True:
    pass
```

Will take 100% of CPU time.

`time.sleep` should take roughly 0% CPU time as it uses system functions to pause execution:

> Changed in version 3.11: On Unix, the clock_nanosleep() and nanosleep() functions are now used if available. On Windows, a waitable timer is now used.

This is expected and documented behavior, even if it may not be intuitive.